# Change value of variable in Sources --> Scope --> Local in ChromeDevTools-GUI

Tags: javascript, scope, google-chrome-devtools, uint8array

I'm completly new to ChromeDev-Tools so maybe I just oversee something. 
This is a Screenshot of the value I want to change in a javascript when it reaches my breakpoint.

[image]

I need to read the value in Screenshot and change it. Is there a way to do this in GUI with copy paste? Or do i have to code this? With right click I can only Copy property Patch, why not he value? Or do I have to enter some editing mode?

Thanks for helping a beginner.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Console tab for this. You can type `a` and it will display the value of the variable, and you can assign to `a` to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it:

```js
JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Uint8Array(a)))
```

But I don't know how to get the changed string back as value for the array...